# Each grep result to different file

Tags: awk, grep

I have something like `grep "keyword" -B 3 log`. It show a lot of results like:

```
  some trash
  unique_id=42
  one more trash
  keyword and usefull info
```

How can I save each `grep` result into separate file with `unique_id` value as name?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on a better suited Stack Exchange site. In future, please only post your question on a single Stack Exchange site. For more information, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295837/each-grep-result-to-different-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other stuff is really trash, I would use this:

```
awk -F'=' '/unique_id/{f=$2} /keyword/{print > f}' file.txt
```

So, every time you see `unique_id` save whatever follows the `=` as the filename. Then, whenever you see the keyword, output that line to the filename you saved previously.

If you do want to have the 3 previous lines:

```
awk -F'=' '/unique_id/{f=$2} /keyword/{print p3,p2,p1,$0 > f} {p3=p2;p2=p1;p1=$0}' OFS='\n' file.txt
```

I am just using 3 variables, `p3`, `p2` and `p1` to refer to the previous lines and updating them after each line is processed by *"shuffling them all along by one"*.